# Какие операнды интерпретатор ОЖИДАЕТ увидеть при использовании операторов сравнения PHP?

Tags: php

Привет.

Вопрос по теории *PHP* по операторам сравнения. Это операторы <,>,<=,>=,==!...

*Чтобы понимать, что будет в результате операции, надо понять ДВЕ вещи* :

1. *Какого типа операнды интерпретатор ОЖИДАЕТ увидеть при использовании оператора сравнения*.
2. *Как интерпретатор конвертирует один тип данных в другой*.

Всего есть 8 типов данных в языке *PHP* . Вопрос - какой тип данных ожидает увидеть интерпретатор при разных комбинациях операндов и операторов, например, сравнение строки с числом целым, строки с булевым типом, числ целого с булевым типом, числа вещественного с булевым типом, число и *NULL*, *NULL* и массив...

**Если я сравниваю две строки между собой, то получается неоднозначность. Как разрешить неоднозначность?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> если операнд 1 null или string, а второй операнд string, то NULL
>   преобразуется в "", числовое или лексическое сравнение. не понимаю

Это значит, что следующее выражение

```
NULL == "строка"
```

будет преобразовано в

```
"" == "строка"
```

и дальнейшее сравнение будет идти по правилам для двух строк.

Цитата с той же страницы, чуть выше:

> В случае, если вы сравниваете число со строкой или две строки,
>   содержащие числа, каждая строка будет [преобразована в число](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), и
>   сравниваться они будут как числа.

То есть будет произведено числовое сравнение:

```
"0" > "-1"    // да
"55" > "221"  // нет
"44" > "22"   // да
44 > "88"     // нет
44 > "abc"    // да
```

Если же ни одна из строк в число не преобразуется, то будет произведено лексическое сравнение:

```
"a" > "b"      // нет
"abc" > "acb"  // нет
"def" > "acb"  // да
"44" > "abc"   // нет
```

Comment: оценил. спасибо за ответ

Comment: возник вопрос. я добавил рисунок в вопрос. если у меня сравнивается строка со строкой, то по таблице получается два разных варианта сравнения. неоднозначность

Comment: @Dimon, нет там никакой неоднозначности. Создатели таблицы предполагают, что смотрящий на неё догадается: речь идёт о всех возможных комбинациях ("строка-ресурс", "число-массив", etc), перечисление всех вариантов которых заняло бы слишком много места. А сравнение "строка-строка" (как и "число-число", и "массив-массив") всегда проходят по алгоритмам, которые указаны в таблице отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос достаточно объёмен, к тому же подробно описывается в различных мануалах, например: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Если коротко, существует определенный алгоритм, которым пользуется интерпретатор PHP, когда встречает в сравнении различные типы данных. Он описан в статье

Comment: В принципе 4 скролла, вполне можно сюда перенести, сославшись ;-)

Comment: там таблица приведена. видел эту таблицу раньше, не понимаю, как работает таблица. например, взять строку 1. пишут, если операнд 1 null или string, а второй операнд string, то NULL преобразуется в "", числовое или лексическое сравнение. не понимаю, "NULL преобразуется в "", числовое или лексическое сравнение"

Comment: @Dimon если вы пытаетесь сравнить null со строкой, то nul будет преобразован в строку нулевой длины, а затем будет проведено сравнение строк. «Числовое или лексическое» это значит, что строки будут сравнены по буквам, но если в одной из строк есть число, каждая строка будет преобразована в число, (пустая преобразуется в 0) и сравниваться они будут как числа.